# Images not displaying in html

Tags: html

I have what I think should be a very simple problem. I have seen several post on how align imges horizontally on a page, but never vertically. What I want is my images to come one below the other. And I have seen that tables should be used for tabular data not images. When I put my imges they align themselves horizontally, i.e. the next image comes to the right of the first. So I use a table. But then the images do not show.
Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<TABLE BORDER="0" width="100%">
<TR>
<TD align="center"><img src="WRF_OUTPUT/Precip_T+03_d01_GrADS.png" width="80%">
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD align="center"><img src="WRF_OUTPUT/Precip_T+06_d01_GrADS.png" width="80%">
 </TD>
<TR>
<TD align="center"><img src="WRF_OUTPUT/Precip_T+09_d01_GrADS.png" width="80%">
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</body>
</html>
```

I thought I used such code before and it worked. What could I be doing wrong? I only see a frame with a small broken image in the top right corner.
Please help.

Comment: Can you share a demo with the images you are using or links to them?

Comment: It's probably some issue in your environment. I've checked it with Mozilla Firefox and IE (even Edge) and it works as you want: one image below the other(s). Anyway, I recommend to use lowercase letters for your tags.

Comment: Are you sure WRF_OUTPUT is a subfolder of the current runtime folder? Anyway try adding something else to each cell, like this: `<TD align="center">AAA<img src=` and `<TD align="center">BBB<img src=` to see where the cells show up.

Comment: The default display of images is `"inline"` so that means one after the other horizontally, but you can change that to `"display: block"` to make them display vertically as block elements, or take all the available width of the container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I put my imges they align themselves horizontally, i.e. the next image comes to the right of the first. So I use a table

So you want to display the images vertically, well you don't need tables to do that

Here is an example using the full width of the container

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#img-container {
  width: 300px;
}
#img-container img {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="img-container">
  <img src="https://kineticrehab.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/wp-cloudy-simple.png" alt="sky paint">
  <img src="https://kineticrehab.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/wp-cloudy-simple.png" alt="sky paint">
  <img src="https://kineticrehab.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/wp-cloudy-simple.png" alt="sky paint">
  <img src="https://kineticrehab.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/wp-cloudy-simple.png" alt="sky paint">
  <img src="https://kineticrehab.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/wp-cloudy-simple.png" alt="sky paint">
</div>
```

Here is an example using `display: block`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://kineticrehab.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/wp-cloudy-simple.png" alt="sky paint">
<img src="https://kineticrehab.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/wp-cloudy-simple.png" alt="sky paint">
<img src="https://kineticrehab.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/wp-cloudy-simple.png" alt="sky paint">
<img src="https://kineticrehab.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/wp-cloudy-simple.png" alt="sky paint">
<img src="https://kineticrehab.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/wp-cloudy-simple.png" alt="sky paint">
```

But if you still want to use tables then you can do this

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 0;
}
img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td><img src="https://kineticrehab.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/wp-cloudy-simple.png" alt="sky paint"></td></tr>
  <tr><td><img src="https://kineticrehab.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/wp-cloudy-simple.png" alt="sky paint"></td></tr>
  <tr><td><img src="https://kineticrehab.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/wp-cloudy-simple.png" alt="sky paint"></td></tr>
  <tr><td><img src="https://kineticrehab.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/wp-cloudy-simple.png" alt="sky paint"></td></tr>
  <tr><td><img src="https://kineticrehab.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/wp-cloudy-simple.png" alt="sky paint"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think I can almost certainly confirm that it is my environment which is not good. At the time of posting I was working in Linux Ubuntu 18.04. Then I moved to Windows 10 and tried both code snippets from SaymoinSam. I get the same result. I have put the html document in the same folder as the images, so no path in img src=. Thank you very all, and especially SaymoinSam for the code. You are great.

Comment: You are welcome, actually I didn't see that you have a problem with images path, in your case you need the html file to be in the current directory that contains your `WRF_OUTPUT` folder

Comment: Thank you very much @SaymoinSam. I can accept your answer. This time am getting a display but it is black with message that image cannot be displayed because it has errors. So I think my environment is not ok. Otherwise all your answers work. Thank you.